# node debug / inspect require returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, read-eval-print-loop

I wanted to have a convenience "node shell" that loaded some commonly used models so I could interact with them and the database.  Seems `node inspect app_shell.js` fails to import (`require`) the script whilst claiming to have done so.

File structure:

```
./test
    app_shell.js
    user.js
```

`app_shell.js` contents:

```
console.log("Script loads useful models for manual interaction in shell.");
var User = require("./user");
debugger;
```

`user.js` contents:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.User = {some: "user"};
```

Running app_shell.js with debug:

```
$ node inspect app_shell.js
< Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/5f48d8f1-a77b-4a1c-838e-7fb51a3b3337
< For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
< Debugger attached.
Break on start in app_shell.js:1
> 1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { console.log("Script loads useful models for manual interaction in shell.");
  2 var User = require("./user");
debug> repl
Press Ctrl + C to leave debug repl
> User
undefined
> User = require("./user");
undefined
> User
{ User: Object, __esModule: true }
```

There must be something trivial I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node debug has started but it has not yet run the file.  When you type `repl` it does not enter the file at the debugger point but instead at the top.  `var User ...` has caused `User` to be declared but not initialised hence the value of `undefined`.

**Solution:**

Press `c` to continue to your `debugger` point and then `repl` to start the REPL session.